# How to handle/mock imported function with imported constant?

Tags: javascript, testing, vitest

I have problem that **articleListedToggleChapter.ts** is not able to load DOM structure I have prepared in test because the const chapters in that script is imported from another file **articleListedElements.ts**. I tried mock chapters but without success? THX!

I have this JavaScript:

```
// articleListedToggleChapter.ts
import { articleListedState as state } from './articleListedState';
import { chapters } from './articleListedElements';

const CLASS_ARTICLE_LISTED_CHAPTER = 'article-listed-chapter';

export const articleListedToggleChapter = () => {
  chapters.forEach((chapter: HTMLDivElement) => {
    const CLASS_ACTIVE = `${CLASS_ARTICLE_LISTED_CHAPTER}--active`;
    const chapterNumber = Number(chapter.getAttribute(`data-${CLASS_ARTICLE_LISTED_CHAPTER}`));

    if (chapterNumber === state.getActiveChapter()) {
      chapter.classList.add(CLASS_ACTIVE);
    } else if (chapter.classList.contains(CLASS_ACTIVE)) {
      chapter.classList.remove(CLASS_ACTIVE);
    }
  });
};
```

This is a helper file which contains more constants:

```
// articleListedElements.ts
export const chapters: NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement> = document.querySelectorAll(
  '[data-article-listed-chapter]'
);

// contains more component elements
```

Unit test:

```
// articleListedToggleChapter.test.ts
import { describe, it, expect, beforeEach, vi } from 'vitest';

import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

import { articleListedToggleChapter } from './articleListedToggleChapter';
import { articleListedState } from './articleListedState';

vi.mock('./articleListedState', () => ({
  articleListedState: {
    getActiveChapter: vi.fn(),
    setActiveChapter: vi.fn(),
  },
}));

const htmlDocumentContent = `<!doctype html>
    <html lang="cs">
        <head></head>
        <body>
          <div data-article-listed="">
            <section class="article-listed-chapter" data-article-listed-chapter="1"></section>
            <section class="article-listed-chapter" data-article-listed-chapter="2"></section>
            <section class="article-listed-chapter" data-article-listed-chapter="3"></section>
            <section class="article-listed-chapter" data-article-listed-chapter="4"></section>
            <section class="article-listed-chapter" data-article-listed-chapter="5"></section>
        </body>
    </html>`;

describe('articleListedToggleChapter', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    vi.clearAllMocks();

    const dom = new JSDOM(htmlDocumentContent, {
      runScripts: 'dangerously',
      resources: 'usable',
    });
    const { document } = dom.window;

    vi.stubGlobal('window', dom.window);
    vi.stubGlobal('document', document);

    // Reset the active chapter before each test
    articleListedState.setActiveChapter(0);

    // Reset the chapter classes before each test
    const chapters = document.querySelectorAll('.article-listed-chapter');
    chapters.forEach((chapter) => {
      chapter.classList.remove('article-listed-chapter--active');
    });
  });

  it('should add the active class to the active chapter', () => {
    // Set the active chapter to the first chapter
    articleListedState.setActiveChapter(1);

    // Act
    articleListedToggleChapter();

    const chapters = document.querySelectorAll('.article-listed-chapter');
    // Check that the first chapter has the active class
    expect(chapters[0].classList.contains('article-listed-chapter--active')).toBe(true);
    expect(chapters[1].classList.contains('article-listed-chapter--active')).toBe(false);
    expect(chapters[2].classList.contains('article-listed-chapter--active')).toBe(false);
  });

});
```